# ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I've just updated to the latest Mac OS Maverick and now when opening apps in the terminal I'm hit with the following message(s). Any idea on how to solve this? Thx in advance!

ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.

To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247'

```
[app]$rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin' is not at first place usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries, it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p195'.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Checking requirements for smf.
Installing requirements for smf.
anthonypanepinto password required for 'sm get head': 
Updating system..
Installing required package: libtool..........................
Error running 'requirements_smf_lib_install libtool',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1382766047_ruby-2.0.0-p247/package_install_libtool.log
Failed installation package: libtool of: libtool, gdbm.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Comment: `ruby-2.0.0-p247` is good. Install it!!!

Comment: thanks Amit, however I'm still getting the same above error when trying to install ruby-2.0.0-p247 using rvm. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to run:

```
rvmsudo rvm get head    # update rvm
rvm autolibs homebrew   # tell rvm to use homebrew
rvm install 2.0.0       # install ruby
rvm use 2.0.0 --default # use ruby and make it default
```

this is leftover after railsinstaller ... I think it can be automated - need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks mpapis, but I'm still getting this error when trying the above: No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Installing requirements for osx_brew.
Updating system.........
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1382767455_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

Comment: so the first part is a warning not an error, the second part is different error, make sure `brew update` works as expected and then continue with ruby installation.

Answer (score 11):

I see some guys still have the issue, I was one of them. After running the instructions from mpapis I still couldn't install ruby 2.0.0 so I did this

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=1
```

That did the trick for me.